# is it possible to extract the exact upload time of a youtube video using python?

Tags: python, youtube

I managed to obtain titles and upload dates of all videos of any given youtube channel using either the scrapetube module or simply urllib (request) and re.

E.g., to obtain the date, I would first get the ids of all videos of a YT channel:

```
videos = scrapetube.get_channel(
    channel_url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/arminvanbuuren/videos",
    sort_by = "newest"
)

videoIds = [video["videoId"] for video in videos]
videoTitles = [video["title"]["runs"][0]["text"] for video in videos]
```

Then, I can generate from that YT links for each video of that channel, visit the page and extract the date from the source code:

```
# create go to link 
df["vlink"] = df["id"].apply(lambda id: f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={id}")

def extract_date(str):
    with urlopen(str) as f:
        html = f.read().decode("utf8")
    date_catch = '"(20\d+-\d+-\d+)"'
    date = re.findall(date_catch, html)[0]
    return(date)

df["date"] = df["vlink"].apply(extract_date)
```

I would however also like to obtain somehow the exact upload date. I could not find that information in the source code of the youtube website for any particular video nor an example how anyone did this otherwise using Python. If you know how to do it, would be great if you share it. Some videos that were live videos seem to have information on the upload date in the source code but most videos dont have it (at least I did not find it).

It would be great if the approach would be freely available and does not require any subscriptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)#[status.publishAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.publishAt).
The following Python script shows how to use the YouTube Data API v3 to get the `publishAt` field of `snippet` for a given video.

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    "youtube", "v3", developerKey='AIzaSy...'
)

request = youtube.videos().list(
    part="snippet",
    id="VIDEO_ID"
)
response = request.execute()

print(response['items'][0]['snippet']['publishedAt'])
```

For instance with `VIDEO_ID` [`jNQXAC9IVRw`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw) you would get: `2005-04-24T03:31:52Z`

Comment: thank you Benjamin. Am I correct that I would need a developerkey for that which I can only obtain by paying? Or at least I need to use Google cloud which was not free of charge. If I am correct, do you know ways how to get this without having to subscribe anywhere?

Comment: You need a developer key. Note that the developer key is available for free, no need to provide a credit card or whatsoever, you just need a Google account and follow [this procedure](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#before-you-start).